# Pandas Error when creating a pivot table (KeyError)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, keyerror

I am trying to create a pivot table from a Dataframe using Pandas. Given below is the view of my Dataframe.

```
category,date,type1,type2,total
PROD_A,2018-10-01,2,2,4
PROD_A,2018-10-02,2,0,2
PROD_B,2018-10-01,0,0,0
PROD_A,2018-10-03,0,0,0
```

I am trying to create a pivot and save the output to an excel file

```
Summary = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['total'], index=['category'], columns='date')

Summary.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary')
```

I get the below error

```
KeyError : 'total'
```

Could anyone guide me where am I gong wrong with this. Thanks

Updating on the datatype:

```
category   object
date       object
type1      int64
type2      int64
total      float64
dtype:     object
```

Output of df.head():

```
category,date,type1,type2,total
PROD_A,2018-10-01,2,2,4
PROD_A,2018-10-02,2,0,2
PROD_B,2018-10-01,0,0,0
PROD_A,2018-10-03,0,0,0
PROD_B,2018-10-03,2,3,5
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you be a bit more specific where the error is occurring and how your data frame looks like?

Comment: @JanTrienes, I have included the datatypes of the columns in the Dataframe, will that help..

Comment: One idea - How working `Summary = pd.pivot_table(df, values='total', index='category', columns='date')`

Comment: Can you add the output of `df.head()`?

Comment: Check `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: @JanTrienes have updated my initial post with a view of the output for df.head()

Comment: Also, which pandas version are you using.

Comment: @jezrael, the output for the print statment is:    ['name','date','type1','type2','total']

Comment: Pandas version is '0.23.0'

Comment: @KevinNash - for me it working nice, no keyerror

Comment: @jezrael could this be because I am trying to save the pivot table to an excel file using "xlsxwriter" library

Comment: If using `Summary = pd.pivot_table(df, values='total', index='category', columns='date')` then no problem?

Comment: @jezrael, Getting a message "pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"

Comment: @KevinNash - I dont understand why, because `total` is floats, `total      float64`.

Comment: @jezrael, I just tried the below and now the table appears df['total'] = df['total'].astype('float64'). But the index value of category does not appear. Not sure why

Comment: Maybe need `Summary = pd.pivot_table(df, values='total', index='category', columns='date').reset_index()`

Comment: Awesome thanks @jezrael. That worked..

Comment: @KevinNash - Created answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `['total']`, it create `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
Summary = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['total'], index=['category'], columns='date')

print (Summary)

              total                      
date     2018-10-01 2018-10-02 2018-10-03
category                                 
PROD_A          4.0        2.0        0.0
PROD_B          0.0        NaN        NaN
```

Solution is use remove it:

```
Summary = pd.pivot_table(df, values='total', index='category', columns='date')
print (Summary)
date      2018-10-01  2018-10-02  2018-10-03
category                                    
PROD_A           4.0         2.0         0.0
PROD_B           0.0         NaN         NaN
```

Last convert index to column by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
Summary = (pd.pivot_table(df, values='total', index='category', columns='date')
             .reset_index(drop=True))
print (Summary)
date  2018-10-01  2018-10-02  2018-10-03
0            4.0         2.0         0.0
1            0.0         NaN         5.0
```